# Действия над датой, если в столбце есть не только дата

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Имеем массив данных. В нём два столбца содержат дату, разницу в днях между которыми надо найти. Но в одном помимо даты, другие сведения, zum Beispiel: 2020-08-15 04:02:21.559178.
Я захотел приделать к массиву новый столбец, где:

```
payments['padla'] = (pd.to_datetime(payments['date1']) - payments['date2']).dt.days
```

на что машина мне ответствовала,

> unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'Timestamp' and 'str'.

Из чего вывожу, что моя попытка сделать из столбца тип данных дату не удалась. Но даже если бы и да, мне нужны не все данные, а только дата, т.е. первые 10 символов в каждой строке. Индексированием я бы брал значения целиком, а как брать из каждой строки, но не целиком; что-то, похожее на регулярные выражения, но таких я не знаю, чтобы "дай мне первые 10 символов из каждой строки". Спасибо.

Comment: Я не вижу в приведенном примере никаких "других сведений" кроме даты. Преобразуйте оба столбца в datetime и находите между нами разницу.

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе небольшой, но воспроизводимый пример входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: а как? ````import datetime
date1 = payments['ts']
date2 = payments['date']
payments['padla'] = (datetime.datetime.date1() - datetime.datetime.date2).days```` что бы я ни делал, машина пишет, что type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'date1'

Comment: так тоже нет ````import datetime
from datetime import date
date1 = datetime.strptime(payments['ts'], '%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S')
date2 = datetime.strptime(payments['date'], '%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S')
payments['delta'] = (date1 - date2).days````  module 'datetime' has no attribute 'strptime'